# A wave is travelling along a string of continously increasing linear density, how does the amplitude change?

Tags: waves

I feel like the amplitude should decrease but I can't prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you assuming constant elasticity?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the simplest case of a linearly-varying density along the string, say
$$
\rho(x) = -a x\,.
$$
(We are taking the slope to be negative for convenience: the solutions are easier to deal with in that case. Note that this means that we can only consider $x<0$ so that $\rho(x)=ax>0$.)
Then, the wave equation is given by
$$
u''(x) = -\frac{\omega^2}{T}\rho(x)u(x) = \frac{\omega^2}{T}ax\,u(x)\,,
$$
after separating out the time-dependence, and $T$ is the (assumed-to-be-constant) tension in the string.  This differential equation is easily solved in terms of Airy functions as
$$
u(x)=
c_1 \text{Ai}\left(x \sqrt[3]{\frac{a \omega ^2}{T}}\right)+c_2 \text{Bi}\left(x
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{a \omega ^2}{T}}\right)\,.
$$
Let's apply boundary condition at $x=0$ that the derivative of this function is zero (so that the end of the string is *free*, which is reasonable given that the density goes to zero there; we don't have to do this, but the general behavior is the same). The result from applying that boundary condition is
$$
\text{Ai}\left(x \sqrt[3]{\frac{a \omega ^2}{T}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}{\text{Bi}\left(x
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{a \omega ^2}{T}}\right)}\,,
$$
and we can plot this function and the density below:]. We can see that the amplitude *and wavelength* decrease in the direction of *increasing* density.

The wavelength decreases because the *speed* of the wave decreases as the density increases (and frequency is fixed: so speed going down must mean that the wavelength goes down).

There is an alternative WKB analysis that might illuminate the physics of the amplitude a little, and I *think* an argument using the continuity equation for energy would explain why the amplitude decreases.  I'll try to put that together later.

[image]